# SVG filter from another invisible SVG removes target completely

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

So I have 2 SVG elements at my page: one with path and another with filter (I made this to be able to apply that filter to multiple SVGs

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 1 1 " class="filter-target">
  <path filter="url(#glow)" d="M 0,0 v 1 h 1 v-1 h-1 z" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="filter-source">
  <defs>
    <filter id="glow">
      <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,0,255)" in="SourceAlpha" result="makeBlue" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="makeBlue"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Everything was ok but then I decided to hide second SVG to prevent layout issues. So I made the following CSS:

```
.filter-source {
  display: none;
}
.filter-target {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px red dashed;
}
```

As a result, `path` with `filter` attribute disappeared too, just like browser removed second SVG completely instead hiding.

Got the same effect at Chrome 76 and Firefox 60 under Linux.

Is it a bug or spec?

[Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/KirillZotov/4Lnaexwz/5/)

Comment: The spec is changing to reflect the reality that browser's won't/can't implement it as written. If you use display: none your effects (filters/clip-paths/masks) will not work.

Comment: some type of magic..

Answer (score 1):

The filter inherits the property `display: none`, so nothing is displayed in the visible `svg`. I think you should remove the `.filter-source` css code and simply add `width="0" height="0"` to the second svg:

```css
.filter-target {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px red dashed;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 1 1 " class="filter-target">
  <path filter="url(#glow)" d="M 0,0 v 1 h 1 v-1 h-1 z" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="filter-source" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="glow">
      <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,0,255)" in="SourceAlpha" result="makeBlue" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="makeBlue"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
Now the layout is not interrumpted
```

EDIT after comments

1. `Why path stays visible when I return display:none back?`
   This is a question about browser behavior. I see it happens in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Obviously, the correct behavior is that of Firefox.
2. `documentation you referenced says "it does not prevent elements from being referenced by other elements"`
   The element is being referenced, but its `display` property is `none`, and that is why you see no color. You are applying an invisible filter.
3. `display property is not inherited`
   The third paragraph of the document reads:

   When applied to a container element, setting display to none causes the 
   container and all of its children to be invisible; thus, it acts on groups 
   of elements as a group. This means that any child of an element with 
   display="none" will never be rendered even if the child has a value for 
   display other than none.

Bear in mind that we are talking about svg `display`, rather than css `display`.

Comment: I already made `.filter-source` invisible with similar trick so the question is more about this particular behavior.Really strange is that if I add `display: block` to `.filter-source` using developer console and then remove it, `.filter-target` content becomes visible

Comment: As I said in the answer, the `display` property is inherited, which means that your filter has the property `display="none"`. This is working as expected. You can see more details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/display . If you remove the `display` property, the default value is `inline`, so it should get rendered.

Comment: Why `path` stays visible when I return `display:none` back?

Comment: Also, there 2 more things:
1) documentation you referenced says "it does not prevent elements from being referenced by other elements", and
2) `display` property is not inherited

Comment: Absolutely agree, seems that browser does skips applying invisible filter, but I still can not find any spec to apply here. Everything is about rendering element itself but not about how it affects _other_ elements.

Comment: The w3c are going to change spec will change to reflect what browsers can/will implement.