# Animating an SVG Filter in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am trying to apply this filter effect in React on an SVG but have it only triggered "onMouseEnter" within the svg itself.

```
<filter id="custom-noise">
            <feTurbulence
              baseFrequency="0.7,0.8"
              seed="0"
              type="fractalNoise"
              result="static"
            >
              <animate
                attributeName="baseFrequency"
                values="0,01;0.1,1"
                dur="3000ms"
                repeatCount="1"
                begin="mySvgId.mouseenter"
              />
              <animate
                attributeName="baseFrequency"
                values="0.01,1;1,1"
                dur="3000ms"
                repeatCount="1"
                begin="mySvgId.mouseenter"
              />
            </feTurbulence>
            <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="static" scale="0">
              <animate
                attributeName="scale"
                values="0;40;0"
                dur="3000ms"
                repeatCount="1"
                begin="mySvgId.mouseenter"
              />
            </feDisplacementMap>
          </filter>
```

It works on when using vanilla HTML & CSS so I'm inclined to think the issue is with the "begin" attribute. How am I supposed to use it in React or is there another mistake I'm making?
Any ideas?

Edit: I have narrowed down the issue to the animate tag's "begin" attribute. When I remove it the animated filter plays as usual. I could be passing wrong values to it but I cannot find a source to guide me on what to pass.
Here is a snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/long-cookies-foj7uo?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: [Looks okay to me](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-maria-g6hmbt?file=/src/App.tsx). Are you providing that `id` prop to some element?

Comment: I am yea. When I remove the "begin" attribute from each the filter animation works. So I'm now positive the issue lies there.
Let me show you how I'm doing it.

Comment: @motto I've edited my question. Have a look at my example.

Comment: Remove the `display: none` from the `<svg>` that defines the filter. The [filter inherits the `display: none`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58197430/21146235) so it's disabled. Plenty of other ways to hide your zero-content svg element though!

Comment: Interesting. It seems to work whether I use ```display: none``` or make the height and width 0;
Also it seems to work for both the image AND the svg in the sandbox example but it doesn't work in my project.

Comment: why have you two copies of the animate element for baseFrequency?

Comment: @MichaelMullany I was trying different values. The latest definition is what applies so I would just comment out the lower one to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but forgot to update this post.
In the link I'll provide below, you'll find a component that accepts an id and creates the SVG filter. The problem was the nature of the id I was passing, that is, if you pass an id that has a hyphen in it, it won't work. I'm not exactly sure why but that was the reason but id must not have any hyphen and it'll work.

For example, passing "myCard" will work but "my-card" will not work.

Have a look here for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/long-cookies-foj7uo?file=/src/App.tsx.